# Will two rotating disks in a fluid be 'attracted' to each other?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, vortex

Imagine two rotating disks in a fluid like this drawing here:

[image]

The rotating disks will create a rotating flow by friction in the fluid. The flow between the disks will be higher velocity than the velocity outside of the disks it seems. Then given bernouilli's principle since the velocity of the fluid between the disks is higher, the pressure will drop more. Thus there will be a pressure differential over the rotating disk, since then:
$$ P_1 > P_2 $$

Would the rotating disks get pushed towards eachother? Is it possible to quantify this relationship?